# Does PHP have boolean operators that don't short circuit?

Tags: php, function, return, boolean

Is it possible, in PHP, to combine several statements with a boolean operator that is equivalent to && but doesn't short circuit?

What I want to achieve is that I can call several functions, return true if all of those functions return true, and false if any of them failed, *but still call all of the functions*.

What I would like to do is:

```
return do_something() __ do_something_else() __ fetch_coffee();
                      ^^ magic operator goes ^^ and here
```

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
$r1 = do_something();
$r2 = do_something_else();
$r3 = fetch_coffee();

return $r1 && $r2 && $r3;
```

Or this:

```
$r = true;
$r = do_something() && $r;
$r = do_something_else() && $r;
$r = fetch_coffee() && $r;

return $r;
```

both of which should work, but they feel a bit kludgy. I was wondering: are there any other ways do this in a nice and readable way?

Comment: `return do_something() && do_something_else() && ...;`

Comment: @u_mulder That won't call all the functions because of short-circuiting.

Comment: The first version seems clearer to me. But SO isn't the appropriate place for style questions like this.

Comment: The first version seems the most readable IMHO

Comment: You should probably add a comment saying that you need to call all the functions, so someone doesn't rewrite it like @u_mulder did.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not necessarily looking for style; maybe there are non-short-circuiting boolean operators or something similar that could be used here. Something that I haven't thought of.

Comment: I can remove the question if it is inappropriate here. Is there a place that's better suited where I could ask it?

Comment: SO is for helping you fix code that doesn't work, not finding different ways to write working code.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: @Barmar This would be off-topic on Code Review as it is a "generic best practice" question.

Comment: You could define a function like `all_true(...$args)` that returns true if all the arguments are true, then use `return all_true(do_something(), do_something_else(), fetch_coffee());`. There's no short-circuiting in argument evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

To make the function more clear, I would just use the first version with clearer variable naming...

```
$somethingOK = do_something();
$somethingElseOK = do_something_else();
$coffeeOK = fetch_coffee();

return $somethingOK && $somethingElseOK && $coffeeOK;
```